# Error when running Meteor 1.2 Android / Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, meteor

I keep getting the following error when I run `meteor run android -- verbose`

ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/tinzors/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/tinzors/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed: /Users/tinzors/Documents/petrocon/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator

Anyone getting this too and/or know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any virtual devices set up. You can set one up pretty easily in Android Studio.

Tools->Android->Android AVD Manager.

Or if you have an android device you and have developer options enabled on your phone you can run this and it will install right on your phone:

```
meteor run android-device
```